# Are there any fields in a django model that the user doesn't fill in but the computer does? (CS50 Project 2)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, cs50

I have created a django form that creates and saves comments to listings. I want the comment to only save to the listing that it is commented to (right now it saves to all the listings). Is there any way to tell the webpage which listing to save it to and which user wrote the comment?

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def listing(request, id):
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CommentForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save()
            comment.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
               "auction_listing": listing,
               "form": form,
               "comments": Comments.objects.all() 
               })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": form,
        "comments": Comments.objects.all()
    })
```

html

```
<img src ="{{ auction_listing.image }}" style = "height: 10%; width: 10%;">
    <h4 class = "text">{{ auction_listing.title }}</h4>
    <h6>Description: {{ auction_listing.description }}</h6>
    <h6>Category: {{ auction_listing.category }}</h6> 
    <h6>Price: ${{ auction_listing.bid }}</h6>

    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Save">
    </form>

    {% for comment in comments %}
        <h6> {{ comment.comment }} </h6>
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for all the help!

This is the error I am now receiving when I try to save a new comment. Let me know if you need to see the comment form.

```
IntegrityError at /listing/1/
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_comments.listing_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing/1/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_comments.listing_id
```

Answer (score 0):

***I want the comment to only save to the listing that it is commented to*** - In order to save comments to current or specific listing you've to create a relation between comment and listing.

Update your comment model like this

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # for one-to-many relation
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

and while saving your form pass listing object and while rendering filter it with current listing

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def listing(request, id):
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    comment_obj = Comments.objects.filter(listing=listing) 
    form = CommentForm() # you have to initialize form properly
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.listing = listing
            comment.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
               "auction_listing": listing,
               "form": form,
               "comments": comment_obj
               })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": form,
        "comments": comment_obj
    })
```

I'll suggest to look at [**`ForeignKey.related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: when I try to makemigrations after adding your change to the model, I receive this error:  `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'listing' to comments without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py` I also receive an error in the webpage `no such column: auctions_comments.listing_id` How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello @skateb2020 you've to option first you can add `null=True` to your listing eg. `listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE, bull=True)` or if you don't want to add **null** attribute then you can delete all you migrations and db.sqlite file and run makemigrations & migrate.

Comment: if I add the null to my listing model, I receive this error ` listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
NameError: name Listings is not defined`. I also am now receiving this error (if I remove the null because the webpage won't even load with the other error message) `OperationalError at /listing/2/
no such column: auctions_comments.listing_id`. Do you know how to fix these problems?

Comment: *NameError: name Listings* - How you imported **Listings** model check if it's correct

Comment: I was able to fix the other problems by deleting all the comments that I had made before. but now I am receiving this error `IntegrityError at /listing/2/
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_comments.listing_id`. I know that it relates back to this line ` <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST">` in the HTML but do not know how to fix it. Could you please help and thank you for all the help so far?

Comment: Hello @skateb2020 can you provide full trace back inside your quesion by making [edit]

Comment: I added the error message to the code. Please let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: Hello @skateb2020 did you checked my code properly I've added this line `comment.listing = listing` check if you have that inside your **listing** view